# no pdf output - view command disabled in LyX (2)

Tags: errors, lyx, incompatibility, amsart

Yesterday I wrote :

I am working in LyX with `documentclass{amsart}` and all was doing well until MiKTeX Update made impossible to produce PDF output, error messages being

- `amscls.sty` not found
  or
- Undefined control sequence `\ifpgfmath@isprime`

Any idea of what's going on?

In fact, after spending time to test compatibility between `amsart` (`\documentclass{amsart}`) and other declared packages (`\usepackage{'package'}`), I found amsart in conflict with igo package (who knows why), and deleting the latter seems to have erased the bug ; the 'view' command (Ctrl+R) is still disabled, but the 'view other formats' command is that far functional, so it looks like doing well again.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by a package conflict, and went away when the package was removed.